# How to check if a string contains exactly two words in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to execute a simple SQL query that will only select those names that are made up of exactly two words

```
SELECT NAME
FROM GROUP
WHERE NAME <Contains exactly two words>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `like` and `not like`:

```
where name like '% %' and not like '% % %'
```

Comment: Beware trailing spaces.

Comment: Yeah, throw TRIM in there (and then lose indexing, so I hope it's not millions of rows)

Comment: `like` with a leading wildcard has to scan anyway.

Comment: @pmbAustin . . . The only way to avoid a full table scan would require a persisted computed column and an index.  I don't even think a full text index would help, but there might be some way.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `LEN()` (of course, I assume there are no trailing spaces):

```
SELECT [NAME]
FROM [GROUP]
WHERE LEN([NAME]) - LEN(REPLACE([NAME], ' ', '')) = 1
```

If the data in the `NAME` column has trailing space, you may use `TRIM` (for SQL Server 2017+) or a combination of `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` for earlier versions:

```
SELECT [NAME]
FROM [GROUP]
WHERE LEN(TRIM([NAME])) - LEN(REPLACE(TRIM([NAME]), ' ', '')) = 1
```

Comment: Very nice. Never considered this. +1 good for teaching me something new. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both words present and exact:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%word1%'
AND column LIKE '%word2%'
```